# Performing ansible tasks on specific hosts

Tags: ansible

I have a group of hosts:

```
[hosts]
host1
host2
host3
```

I would like to run some script on only one of given hosts (doesn't really matter which one), and then in second task, run another script, but only on the two remaining hosts, on which the previous task was not performed.

```
- name: Task to be run on any host from given group of host
  shell: sth
  .
  .

- name: Task to be run on the other 2 hosts from the same group
  shell: sth else
  .
  .
```

I know it can be achieved, eg. using `serial`, though no other ideas. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

There are more options.

1. Run once the first task in the block and put the inventory_hostname into a variable. Run the next task in the loop without the first host. For example

```yaml
- name: Play1
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Task to be run on any host from given group of host
          command: echo {{ inventory_hostname }}
          register: result_first
        - set_fact:
            first_host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      run_once: true
    - name: Task to be run on the other 2 hosts from the same group
      command: echo {{ item }}
      register: result_others
      loop: "{{ groups.all|difference([first_host]) }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ result_first.stdout }}"
          - "{{ result_others.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

give

```yaml
ok: [host1] => 
  msg:
  - host1
  - - host2
    - host3
```

---

2. The next option is to create a group of hosts without the first one. This approach doesn't need delegation. For example

```yaml
- name: Play2
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Task to be run on any host from given group of host
          command: echo {{ inventory_hostname }}
          register: result_first
        - set_fact:
            first_host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        - add_host:
            name: "{{ item }}"
            groups: my_group_without_first_host
            result_first: "{{ result_first }}"
          loop: "{{ groups.all|difference([first_host]) }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: my_group_without_first_host
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Task to be run on the other 2 hosts from the same group
      command: echo {{ inventory_hostname }}
      register: result_others
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ result_first.stdout }}"
          - "{{ result_others.stdout }}"
```

give

```yaml
ok: [host2] => 
  msg:
  - host1
  - host2
ok: [host3] => 
  msg:
  - host1
  - host3
```